# creating a org.w3c.dom.node below another org.w3c.dom.node

Tags: java, dom, w3c

I have a xml document with simple org.w3c.dom.node  nodes inside it . Adding a new node always happens at the end  . However I  want that if I have identified a node with value say 3 , I  should always insert a new node just after this node .

Whenever when  I try to add a node via

```
nodeWithValue3.getParentNode().appendChild(newNode);
```

it always happens at the end of the document .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i took some time to figure the answer , answering here so someone might get help from this

I found that I can do something like below to achieve the same .

```
node nextNode = nodeWithValue3.getNextSibling();
nodeWithValue3.getParentNode().insertBefore(newChildNode, nextNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must read the whole xml file node by node,then write those nodes to a new xml file.During the write operation,you can write a new node once write the specified node,such as nodeWithValue3.